# jQuery Multiple Load Issues

Tags: jquery

I'm working with the follow jQuery snippet:

```
    $('iframe[title="Export"]').load(function() {
        console.log("Export Dialog Loaded");
        $('#master_btnExport',ContentWindow.document).click();
    });

    $('iframe[title="Export Dialog"]').load(function() {
        console.log("Export Options Loaded");
        $('#DataExportSection_MSExcelLink',ContentWindow.document).click();
    });
```

What happens is that the first .load works perfectly and once the iframe is loaded the .click event for master_btnExport fires.

The issue is that click event loads another iframe. The second .load I have is not working in order to fire the click event for the DataExportSection_MSExcelLink.

I tried nesting the second .load inside of the first .load but that didn't work either.

I'm using title= because both the iframes have the same name.

Any insight in what I'm missing?

FYI, jQuery 1.4pre is loaded and cannot load a new version.

Comment: Is this line reached? `console.log("Export Options Loaded");`

Comment: Tip: Instead of using titles, give the iframes IDs.

Comment: Please include your html for each page and how the iframes are created. With your question as-is, we can only guess at why it's not loading.

Comment: @MelanciaUK, the console.log is not reached and the iFrames have no id attribute but has the name attribute.  Both iFrames have the same name, ContentWindow as stated in my initial post above.  If there a way to reference each iFrame with the same name I'm more than willing to use that.

Comment: @tcooc the iframes load without a problem, that isn't the issue.  The issue is clicking on a link within the second iframe window which the second .load in my code isn't reaching, console.log("Export Options Loaded") isn't being executed.

Comment: @primortal I'm asking how the iframes are loaded. Although they load without issue, how they load affects how you need to use the handlers.

Comment: @tcooc Not sure how they are loaded. When clicking on the link in the HTML another dialog box appears.  I know Telerik controls are being used to display the dialog boxes.

Comment: Where is your click event code? Can you add this to the post? You may want to bind the second `.load` within your click event, after you begin loading the iframe. If the element does not exist, it will not be bound.

Comment: @SixteenStudio  The click event for master_btnExport is calling ShowContentInRadWinow function with a line of window.setUrl(content) where content is the URL the iFrame loads.  I would have to digging through Telerik libraries to find what window.setURL does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to get it work using the following

```
$('iframe[title="Export"]').load(function() {
    $('#master_btnExport',ContentWindow.document).click();
    $(this).contents().find('iframe').load(function(){
        eval($(this).contents().find('a[id="DataExportSection_MSExcelLink"]').click().attr('href').replace(/javascript:/i,""));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this work? Possible untested solution...

```
$('iframe[title="Export"]').load(function() {
    console.log("Export Dialog Loaded");
    $('#master_btnExport',ContentWindow.document).click();
});

$(document).on('load', 'iframe[title="Export Dialog"]', function() {
    console.log("Export Options Loaded");
    $('#DataExportSection_MSExcelLink',ContentWindow.document).click();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Chrome is throwing a "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".  I missed one key point.  jQuery 1.4pre is loaded and cannot load a newer version do to restrictions.